# Raspberry Pi 2 B CSI camera multiplexer IC design

Tags: camera

I am working on a project that necessitates connecting two cameras to a Raspberry Pi 2 B. The cameras will **not** be required to take pictures/video at the same time. I have done the following research for the solution:

MIPI switching 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=67553&p=797174

Raspcam multiplexer 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=61904&p=460203

Multiple cameras 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=50142

IVPort project 
https://hackaday.io/project/2847-ivport-raspberry-pi-camera-module-multiplexer

Camera module multiplexer 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52213&p=447084

I would like to implement the solution proposed by that last forum post.

I am using this image for a visual reference
[image: CSI specification]

For the CSI transmitter/receiver (top half), it appears as though I am limited to the FSA642 IC.
Datasheet: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FS/FSA642.pdf

As for the CCI master/slave, I saw the PCA9543A being suggested.
Datasheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/PCA9543A_43B_43C-64811.pdf

To switch between cameras, I would use a GPIO pin from the Pi to switch the selection pins of the two ICs. Switching time does not matter unless it is unreasonable (>3 seconds). It will basically fulfil the same purpose as a standard smart phone switching from a front-facing camera to a rear-facing camera.

All that remains are two questions in my mind. First and foremost, would this idea work at all as I have it? Second, what would I do with the CAM_GPIO and CAM_CLK pins as shown in the [Raspberry Pi schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Raspberry-Pi-Schematics-R1.0.pdf) (page 4)? It seems from [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=61082) that I can use a standard multiplexer to switch those.

Thank you in advance for any insight you may provide.

Note: I should also mention I am not interested in paying $80 for the IVPort and I am restricted to using the official camera modules.

Comment: I would just buy another Pi (an A+ should do the job)

Comment: I wish I could, the project I'm working on has some pretty tight space requirements. I even considered the compute model but I have to use a model B.

Comment: If you weren't tied to a Model B I say perhaps the Pi Zero might help, it has two camera ports IIRC...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following links are helpful, unless you already have the information found there:

Relevant [thread on freescale.com forum](https://community.freescale.com/thread/301812)

Link to [Arducam.com](http://www.arducam.com/multi-camera-adapter-module-raspberry-pi/) with this device:

[image: One image from site showing a RPi and four camera leads connected to device referred to in link]

I personally do not have any competence with Pi's, just been wandering around and picking up some informative links about Pi's for future use.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange community. Those linked to products look interesting and relevant but actually getting a switching unit may not be so easy.  Do you have any experience of similar camera multiplexing devices on another platform (e.g. Arduino) type devices?